# Laravel - Filter rows from model by function of another model

Tags: mysql, laravel, model

I have A model of items and model of users.
In the user model has a function that check if the user has permission:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function hasPermission($permission){
        $code = Permission::where('name',$permission)->first()->id-1;
        $total = $this->group->permissions;
        return ($total & pow(2,$code));
    }
}
```

and I am trying to filter items by this function something like:

```
Items::where('sell_price','>',0)->where('user.hasPermission','SellItems');
```

The items model look like:

```
class Items extends Model
{

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you are looking for the whereHas method:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

That should get you up and running!

example as mentioned in the comments (beware, did not test this):

```
Item::whereHas('user', function($q) use ($permission) {
    //your permission query here you can use $permission;
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly it
I need to insert arguments into the function

Comment: Why wouldn't this be possible you can use variables inside the closure. just pass them using "use". I'll add an example above

Answer (score 0):

`hasPermission` is at its current state a function that requires the model to have been acquired in order to work so can't really be used as a query.

You can however attempt to write the logic in SQL and use it in a `whereHas`:

```
Items::where('sell_price','>',0)->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
    $query->join('permissions', \DB::raw('users.group|(permissions.id-1)'), '!=', '0')
           ->where('permission.name', 'SellItems');
});
```

This will hopefully get all items associated with a user who has sell permissions.